# DynamoDBMapper Table Generation Creating Only Index

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create tables in DynamoDB using the Java API.

Problem : It creates only the hash key index in the table and no other Attributes.

```
private void createTable(DynamoDBMapper mapper, AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDBClient) {
    CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = mapper.generateCreateTableRequest(InsuranceData.class);
    createTableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(25L, 25L));
    amazonDynamoDBClient.createTable(createTableRequest);
}


 private void run(){
    AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDBClient = getDynamoDBLocalClient();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBClient);
    InsuranceData insuranceData = new InsuranceData();
    createTable(mapper,amazonDynamoDBClient);
 }
```

`POJO class`

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "InsuranceData")
public class InsuranceData {


private Integer siteId;
private String lob;
private InsuranceLobData multiItemLobData;
private InsuranceLobData standaloneLobData;

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "siteId")
public Integer getSiteId() {
    return siteId;
}

public void setSiteId(Integer siteId) {
    this.siteId = siteId;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "F")
public String getLob() {
    return lob;
}

public void setLob(String lob) {
    this.lob = lob;
}

@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = InsuranceLobConverter.class)
public InsuranceLobData getMultiItemLobData() {
    return multiItemLobData;
}

public void setMultiItemLobData(InsuranceLobData multiItemLobData) {
    this.multiItemLobData = multiItemLobData;
}

@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = InsuranceLobConverter.class)
public InsuranceLobData getStandaloneLobData() {
    return standaloneLobData;
}

public void setStandaloneLobData(InsuranceLobData standaloneLobData) {
    this.standaloneLobData = standaloneLobData;
}
}
```

`Converter`

```
public class InsuranceLobConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, InsuranceLobData> {
  private final static Gson gson = new Gson();


@Override
public String convert(InsuranceLobData object) {
    return gson.toJson(object);
}

@Override
public InsuranceLobData unconvert(String object) {
    return gson.fromJson(object, InsuranceLobData.class);
}

}
```

Can anybody see the problem here?

**This Is Resolved**

There was a problem the way I was storing my complex object `InsuranceLobData`.

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class InsuranceLobData   {

private boolean isActive;
private Set<String> locale;
private AbacusData abacusData;
private boolean isActiveForMobile;
private boolean isActiveForDesktop;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "InsuranceLobData{" +
            "isActive=" + isActive +
            ", locale=" + locale +
            ", abacusData=" + abacusData +
            ", isActiveForMobile=" + isActiveForMobile +
            ", isActiveForDesktop=" + isActiveForDesktop +
            '}';
}

public InsuranceLobData(){}


public InsuranceLobData(boolean isActive, Set<String> locale, AbacusData abacusData, boolean isActiveForMobile, boolean isActiveForDesktop) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
    this.locale = locale;
    this.abacusData = abacusData;
    this.isActiveForMobile = isActiveForMobile;
    this.isActiveForDesktop = isActiveForDesktop;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "isActive")
public boolean isActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    isActive = active;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "locale")
public Set<String> getLocale() {
    return locale;
}

public void setLocale(Set<String> locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
}

@DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson
public AbacusData getAbacusData() {
    return abacusData;
}

public void setAbacusData(AbacusData abacusData) {
    this.abacusData = abacusData;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "mobile")
public boolean isActiveForMobile() {
    return isActiveForMobile;
}
public void setActiveForMobile(boolean activeForMobile) {
    isActiveForMobile = activeForMobile;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "desktop")
public boolean isActiveForDesktop() {
    return isActiveForDesktop;
}


public void setActiveForDesktop(boolean activeForDesktop) {
    isActiveForDesktop = activeForDesktop;
}
```

}

**There was no need to add the DynamoDBDocument annotation.     <del>@DynamoDBDocument</del>**

Comment: Did you set the value for Lob i.e. insuranceData.setLob("some data")? I have tried with your mapper class and it works ok for me. I can see the attribute 'F' in table.

Comment: Could you extract the answer from your question and post it as an answer and accept it? It would make this much clearer

Comment: @sm4 done that. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = InsuranceLobConverter.class)
```

was enough for DynamoDB to understand what sort of data i want to store in the database. Probably adding the annotation: `@DynamoDBDocument` to `InsuranceLobData` was confusing for it to understand the way it had to store the data.

So, removing the annotation `@DynamoDBDocument` worked for me.

Hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is - after the table creation why do you see only "siteId" attribute but not "F" in the table? This is expected. Since DynamoDB is a NoSQL database, an empty table would show only partition key and sort key (if exists) as attributes.

You'll be able to see "F" attribute once you have at least one item in the table.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what my question is about. So I'll try adding an item and see if F is added and mark your answer as accepted. Thanks. :)

Comment: It didn't work out. I created an object of InsuranceData with all the values and added an item. It updated just the siteId. I printed the table description.

Comment: Could you show your code for mapper.save()? Do you get any error?

Comment: It is a simple `mapper.save(insuranceData);` and i dont get any error.

Comment: It would help if you update your question with that part of your code.